# Is this correct assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

Can I handle an array like this in assembly?

```
db a 10,20,30,40,50
```

and then say:

```
mov si,0
```

and then refer to an element like this

```
mov AX,a[si]
```

Comment: That would depend on your specific assembler, but I would think not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, yes, but it would be more efficient to write

```
mov si, offset a
mov ax, [si]
```

One more thing: `a` is defined as an array of bytes. And `ax` is 16bit register. So, `mov ax,[si]` will make `ax` to contain first two bytes of `a` (i.e. `al=10`, `ah=20`).

What you probably want is

```
 mov al, [si]
```

or

```
 mov al, a[si]
```

Comment: could u plz explain what offset does??

Comment: in x86 real mode, given the address `offset` returns its...well...[offset from the start of segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Segmented_addressing), i.e. 16bit value that can be combined with segment address, instead of value at that address. Some assemblers guess you want to get address on their own, while some require to be specific and provide `offset` keyword. So, you may experiment to find out if it is necessary in your case

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is allowed/supported.

@elder_george has things at least sort of correct though: you more often want to put the address into a register instead of encoding it into the instruction. In the fairly typical case that you're walking through the array, you might want something like:

```
    mov bx, offset a
    xor si, si
next_char:
    mov al, bx[si]
    ; process al
    inc si
    cmp si, 5
    jle next_char
```

If possible, however, it's often a bit more convenient to process from the end to the beginning:

```
    mov bx, offset a
    mov si, 5
next_char:
    mov al, bx[si]
    ; process al
    dec si
    jnz next_char
```

Or, you can reverse the roles of base and index for another (now mostly out of date) optimization:

```
    mov esi, offset a
    mov ecx, 5
next_char:
    mov al, esi[ecx]
    ; process al
    loop next_char
```

You can only do this particular trick with 32-bit registers though -- ecx can act as a "base" register, but cx cannot (and loop *only* works with [e]cx. Conversely, bx and bp can both act as base registers, but `loop` won't work with them.